# Executing multiple async functions not in parallel Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I have an application that communicates to a device over Bluetooth using BLE. It uses GATT. In simple terms, I send a command to address 1, receive a response on address 2. This is not relevant to the problem, but it helps explain why the "async" function does not retrieve a response in a simple way. So to send a command to a BLE device, I would execute something like this:

```
await btwrite.write(command);
```

.write method is a "`Future<Null>`"

Now the issue is that I have to send multiple commands, and each command is dependent on the previous command. As an example, this is the flow:

```
Command 1 -> Response 1 -> Command 2 -> Response 2
```

I have to wait for a response before sending the next command. I only have ability to send using async functions so I have to call multiple await like this:

```
btread.value.listen((v) {
    print('Response:' + v.toString());
});

await btwrite.write(command1);
await btwrite.write(command2);
```

In this scenario, command2 can return results before command 1. Is there a way to execute multiple "await" methods one after another but only after I make sure that previous execution received a response?

Comment: show code of write method

Comment: You could do something like `btwrite.write(command1).then(btwrite.write(command2).then(...));`

Comment: @jitsm555 https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue, specifically this https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/blob/master/lib/src/bluetooth_characteristic.dart, line 107. This is a plugin, I didn't write this.

Comment: @dev-aentgs Using `.then()` wouldn't help. `await` is syntactic sugar for `.then()` and already serializes the calls to `btwrite.write()`.  The problem here is that the OP needs to wait for each *response*.

Comment: @jamesdlin exactly and the issue is that response does not come from that await function but rather from another listener.

Comment: Doesn't the first await wait for the result before going to second await  statement?

Comment: @Braj, as I have explained, the result will be "null" and it will proceed because the result of execution is not retrieved using that method but on another listener.

Comment: @Braj `await btwrite.write(command1)` presumably completes when the data is *sent* on the "wire", not when the response comes back from the other end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've presented already serializes the calls to `btwrite.write()`.  However, `btwrite.write(command2)` waits only for the *write* for `command1`, not for the corresponding *response*.

I am not familiar with this plugin and am not well-versed in Dart streams, but you possibly could make a helper function that performs the write and obtains a `Future` from the response stream, which is what you actually want to wait on, something like:

```dart
Future<void> write(List<int> command) async {
   // You'll probably want to use `collectBytes` from `package:async` instead.
   Future<List<int>> response = btread.value.first;

   await btwrite.write(command);
   
   var v = await response;
   print('Response:' + v.toString());
}


...

await write(command1);
await write(command2);
```

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for, I will try now

Comment: It is still having an issue, it's not only that response does not come, but even "Response" is not printed

Comment: This helped, I had to add tracking of  "response" commands before ending "write" future

Answer (score 1):

Considering we add a `btResponse` variable to track the received response in the below `Listener`

```
String btResponse;
btread.value.listen((v) {
    print('Response:' + v.toString());
    btResponse = v.toString(); 
});
```

We could do something like :

```
await btwrite.write(command1);
while (true) {
  if(btResponse!=null){
    btResponse = null;
    await btwrite.write(command2);
    break;
  }
}
```

This is a crude suggestion, not sure if it would help.